# How do I disable default Tkinter key commands?

Tags: python, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, tkinter

I'd like to implement my own key command. However when I do, it does both what I tell it and the default command. How do I disable the default command, so that my command is the only one that runs?

This is on Windows 7, BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `return 'break'` at the end of your event handling function.  This tells Tkinter not to propagate the event to default handlers.